# Mocha Custom Reporter - Pass in values

Tags: testing, mocha.js

I have written a custom reporter for mocha.  I would like to be able to pass in variables to it, is there a way to pass in variables?

For example, I would like to pass in a Project and a suite.  My custom reporter then is able to report these results to a 3rd party application, but I need to be able to report the suite and project in the test pass or test fail methods.

Thanks